# Is this set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ compact?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a bounded sequence in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and let $A$ be the set of limit points of $\{a_n\}$.

Then, if I let $B = \{a_n\} \cup A$, is $B$ compact?

It is clear that $B$ is bounded, so all I need to check is that $B$ is closed,

Intuitively, it seems to me that $B$ is closed, but how do I prove/disprove rigorously?

Comment: Does it have all of its limit points?

Comment: @avid19 what do you mean?

Comment: Does $B$ have all of its limit points?

Comment: That is equivalent to checking whether $B$ is closed. isn't it?

Comment: Yes. So I'm asking, does $B$ have all of its limit points?

Comment: @user12345678910 : I think avid19 is trying to ask if you have checked whether or not $B$ contains all its limit point (this is a way to show that $B$ is closed).

Comment: just think if it is possible that there is a sequence in $A$ which has a limit point which is not in $A$, either in $\{a_n\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A\subset \mathbb{R}^n$, and $L$ is the set of limit points, then
$B=A \cup L$ is closed.

Choose $x \notin B$, and consider the sets $C_n=B(x, {1\over n}) \cap B$. Then
there must be some $N$ such that $C_n =\emptyset$ for all $n \ge N$. If not,
we can find $c_n \in C_n \subset  B$, and clearly $c_n \to x$.

Since $c_n \in B$, we can find $a_n \in A$ such that $|a_n-c_n| < {1 \over n}$.
Then $|x-a_n| \le |x-c_n| +|c_n-a_n| < |x-c_n| + {1 \over n}$, and so
$a_n \to x$. However, either $x \in A$ or $x \in L$ and so $x \in B$, which
is a contradiction.

Hence $B^c$ is open, and so $B$ is closed.